# invitation to app does not notify User

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-invite

I try send a invite for my app using javascript and works, the window of invite show and send the invite, but the user dont see any notification. this is the code i use:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

<script>
FB.init({
appId:'APP_ID',
cookie:true,
status:true,
xfbml:true
});

function FacebookInviteFriends()
{
FB.ui({
method: 'apprequests',
message: 'Your Message diaolog',
to: '204302321251236'
});
}

</script>

<a href='#' onclick="FacebookInviteFriends();"> 
Facebook Invite Friends Link
</a>
```

Comment: Is this a canvas game, or a site off-Facebook? If the latter, this isn't supposed to work - the Requests documentation explains it in detail

Answer (score 0):

Hi You just need to go in to the facebook developer and select your app and goes in to the setting of your app and click "Add Platform" and select "App On Facebook" and than add canvas url in it. now try to send invitation and it will show the notification.